# "dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted" appears every time terminal is opened

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, dmesg

I am experiencing an issue on Kubuntu 18.10 where every time I open any form of terminal (Konsole, Yakuake, Xterm) I receive the message

> dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted

in the terminal window. I have tried unrestricing dmesg but the message keeps appearing. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict`?

Comment: @j-money I have and unfortunately it did not fix the issue.

Comment: `echo "kernel.dmesg_restrict=0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf"`?

Comment: @j-money Issue persists after doing that as well.

Comment: @j-money : Confirmed: `kernel.dmesg_restrict=0` has no impact on `dmesg -D` and `dmesg -E`, which produce "dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted"